# How to render component using boolean state values in redux in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a react app where I have 3 boolean variables in redux store and I want to switch between 3 components to render using these boolean values.How can I do it?

Here's my code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column width={1} />
        <Grid.Column width={14}>
            this.props.openCreateForm?<Form/>:</>
            this.props.openViewPopup?<ViewPopup/>:</>
            this.props.openCredsPopup?<CredsPopup/>:</>
        </Grid.Column>             
        <Grid.Column width={1} />
    </Grid.Row>
</Grid>
```

Inside `Grid.Column` I want to render only 1 of these three components.All the boolean values are from redux state.

`Error`

```
react-dom.development.js:24036 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

How can I do this?I am getting a error on this

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: How do you get your state from redux? hooks or connected components?

Comment: I am using `mapStatetoProps` for getting values

Comment: it should be like this `{this.props.openCreateForm?<Form/>:</>}`. was it a typo in question?

Comment: When you're using [JSX syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-build.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper), the compiler will require embedded JavaScript code to be wrapped inside of `{ }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose them within **{ }**

```
const { openCreateForm, openViewPopup, openCredsPopup } = this.props

           <Grid.Column width={14}>
             { openCreateForm ? <Form/> : 
               openViewPopup ? <ViewPopup/> :
               openCredsPopup ? <CredsPopup/> : </> }
           </Grid.Column>
```

or if you don't want nested ternary,

```
           <Grid.Column width={14}>
             { this.props.openCreateForm && <Form/> ||
               this.props.openViewPopup && <ViewPopup/> ||
               this.props.openCredsPopup && <CredsPopup/> || </> }
           </Grid.Column>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { openCreateForm, openViewPopup, openCredsPopup } = this.props

        <Grid>
        <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column width={1} />
            <Grid.Column width={14}>
                {openCreateForm && <Form/>}
                {openViewPopup && <ViewPopup/>}
                {openCredsPopup && <CredsPopup/>}
            </Grid.Column>             
            <Grid.Column width={1} />
        </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
```

Use destructuring to get the props value and use && operator for conditional rendering. It works because in JavaScript, true && expression always evaluates to expression, and false && expression always evaluates to false.

Refer here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator